# Getting HTML SELECT length property in C#

Tags: c#, html, dom

I'm trying to figure out how to grab DOM elements from a webpage. Here is the function I'm using:

```
private void processHTML(String htmlContent)
{
    IHTMLDocument2 htmlDocument = (IHTMLDocument2)new mshtml.HTMLDocument();
    htmlDocument.write(htmlContent);

    IHTMLElementCollection allElements = htmlDocument.all;

    webBrowser1.DocumentText = allElements.item("storytext").innerHTML;
    textBox2.Text = allElements.item("chap_select").length.ToString();
}
```

If I set a breakpoint at either of the last two lines and then check the allElements collection, I'm able to find the SELECT element. It correctly shows the ID as being chap_select and the length property shows 13 for the particular document that is being passed. For some reason the length that is being put into the textBox2 field is 2, however.

Any suggestions on what I'm doing wrong here? I've spent several hours trying to figure this out, but have not been able to find any code samples of somebody trying to grab this property of a SELECT.

Comment: Are you sure you aren't looking at text length when debugging and object length in the textbox's output?

Comment: I tried passing it a page that has a length of 7 in debugging and it also reports a 2 in the textBox2 field there as well. I'd assume that the length would drop to 1 if it were looking at the number of characters in the length, if that's what you were referring to.

This is literally my first c# program working with web pages, and 2nd program in general, so I'm sure that I'm doing something wrong, but cannot tell what.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using `IHTMLDocument2` and `mshtml.HTMLDocument` I suggest using the much easier to work with [HTML Agility Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/).

> What is exactly the Html Agility Pack (HAP)?
>
> This is an agile HTML parser that builds a read/write DOM and supports plain XPATH or XSLT (you actually don't HAVE to understand XPATH nor XSLT to use it, don't worry...). It is a .NET code library that allows you to parse "out of the web" HTML files. The parser is very tolerant with "real world" malformed HTML. The object model is very similar to what proposes System.Xml, but for HTML documents (or streams).

Something like (untested):

```
var doc = new HtmlDocument();
doc.LoadHtml(htmlContent);
textBox2.Text = doc.DocumentNode
            .SelectNodes("//select[@id='chap_select']/option").Count().ToString();
```

Comment: Well, I wanted to see if I could figure out the problem at least, before deciding whether HTML Agility Pack is better. I gave it a try, though. This worked for the webBrowser1 part:  

    `var doc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
    doc.LoadHtml(htmlContent);
    webBrowser1.DocumentText =   doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//*[contains(@id, 'storytext')]").InnerHtml;`  

The line you provided for the option is giving a null exception error. I'm trying to figure that part out.

Comment: This did the trick: `textBox2.Text = (doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//select[@id='chap_select']/option").Count() /2).ToString();`

The problem with the original code was the @ was left off before the  id. I had to add the /2 because the select is repeated on the page, to give the drop-down once at the top and once at the bottom, which doubled the options the script reported.